# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7 >= 7

Tags: java

I'm having trouble putting 14 rows of data from my jTable to my Textfields can you guys help me? I'm new to coding.

```
    try {

        String data = jSubject.getSelectedItem().toString();

        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:dist/Database/./h2database/recordDB", "test", "test");
        Statement st = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        String sql = "Select * from " + data;

        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

        DefaultTableModel a = (DefaultTableModel) jTable2.getModel();
        a.setRowCount(0);
        while (rs.next()) {
            String q = rs.getString("Subjects");

            a.addRow(new Object[]{q});
        }
        JTableHeader th = jTable2.getTableHeader();
        TableColumnModel tcm = th.getColumnModel();
        TableColumn tc = tcm.getColumn(0);
        tc.setHeaderValue("Subjects");
        th.repaint();

        DefaultTableModel xa = (DefaultTableModel) jTable2.getModel();
        // int selectedRowIndex = jTable2.getSelectedRow();

        s1.setText(xa.getValueAt(0, 0).toString());
        s2.setText(xa.getValueAt(1, 0).toString());
        s3.setText(xa.getValueAt(2, 0).toString());
        s4.setText(xa.getValueAt(3, 0).toString());
        s5.setText(xa.getValueAt(4, 0).toString());
        s6.setText(xa.getValueAt(5, 0).toString());
        s7.setText(xa.getValueAt(6, 0).toString());
        s8.setText(xa.getValueAt(7, 0).toString());
        s9.setText(xa.getValueAt(8, 0).toString());
        s10.setText(xa.getValueAt(9, 0).toString());
        s11.setText(xa.getValueAt(10, 0).toString());
        s12.setText(xa.getValueAt(11, 0).toString());
        s13.setText(xa.getValueAt(12, 0).toString());
        s14.setText(xa.getValueAt(13, 0).toString());


    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CBL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CBL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Every time I run the code it always gives me the java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7 >= 7 error.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7 >= 7
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:474)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:648)
at progress.chart.CBL.jSubjectActionPerformed(CBL.java:1750)
at progress.chart.CBL.access$1600(CBL.java:34)
at progress.chart.CBL$19.actionPerformed(CBL.java:1041)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(JComboBox.java:1258)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(JComboBox.java:586)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(JComboBox.java:622)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicComboPopup.java:861)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:290)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$1.processMouseEvent(BasicComboPopup.java:510)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

> This is the full stack trace that you guys wanted

Comment: Post the Stack trace.

Comment: Please paste here the full error list

Comment: Please look now

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you made a mistake in your code. The method call[`DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(int row, int column)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#getValueAt(int,%20int)) throws an exception because you have less than 8 rows. I suggest to check number of rows and stop on the last row. In your code you expect 14 rows but in fact you have less.

Answering your question in the comment:

> It works when I stop at s7.setText(xa.getValueAt(6, 0).toString()); So
>   how can I increase the 7 columns in my Array? Because I wanted to make
>   it 14 or more

1. You have added only 7 rows in the `while` loop above (`a.addRow(new Object[]{q});`). Things might change and you might get less or more rows from your database.
2. I guess this is not good question because it looks like you ask how to write your program. At this moment I give up because I can not write program for you without knowing the requirements etc. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: It works when I stop at
            s7.setText(xa.getValueAt(6, 0).toString());

So how can I increase the 7 columns in my Array? Because I wanted to make it 14 or more

Answer (score 0):

`DefaultTableModel` looks like an array object and maybe `DefaultTableModel`'s array length is under `7`. Therefore when you put in this array `7` or more objects,  `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error occurs.

so, you need to check `DefaultTableModel` object array length

Comment: How can I increase that length?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably Exception found into `xa.getValueAt(7, 0)` `xa.getValueAt(8, 0`)`.....`
So check  the size of `xa` by this line  `DefaultTableModel xa = (DefaultTableModel) jTable2.getModel();`